# How can I run xml in xslt envrionment?

Tags: c++, xml, xslt

This seems dummy questions to ask. But I have no idea doing it.
I figured in CLion, I can configure some xslt file to run xml written text. For example,

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="hannimpeha.xsl" ?>
<settings>
    <case>
        <RNGSettings>
            <RNG>RandomGeneratorStdLib</RNG>
        </RNGSettings>
        <agents>
            <AgentCross>
                <count>100</count>
                 <b1>25</b1>
                <b2>100</b2>
                  <A1>0.1</A1>
                <A2>0.3</A2>
                <cash>1</cash>
                <stock>1</stock>
            </AgentCross>
        </agents>
        <dataItemCollectorClasses>
            <DataCollectorPrice />
            <DataCollectorExcessDemand />
        </dataItemCollectorClasses>
        <numsteps>10000</numsteps>
        <outputname>example_Cross</outputname>
        <deltaT>0.00004</deltaT>
        <writerClass>WriterTXT</writerClass>
        <excessDemandCalculatorSettings>
            <excessDemandCalculatorClass>ExcessDemandCalculatorHarras</excessDemandCalculatorClass>
        </excessDemandCalculatorSettings>
        <priceCalculatorSettings>
            <priceCalculatorClass>PriceCalculatorCross</priceCalculatorClass>
            <theta>2</theta>
            <marketDepth>0.2</marketDepth>
        </priceCalculatorSettings>
        <repetitions>5</repetitions>
        <startPrice>1</startPrice>
    </case>
</settings>
```

and xsl file goes like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:import href="Cross.xml">

         </xsl:import>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It seems to run without error. The point is it does not give me any output either.
What is the problem in the above question?

cf) This question is originally arise from installing this [https://github.com/SABCEMM/](https://github.com/SABBCEMM) and run the examples inside it. The final goal is running

> FinanceSimulation.cpp

under

> /input/examples/Cross.xml

condition.

Comment: It seems from your question that you don't provide any XSLT logic to manipulate your xml. That's why it doesn't give any output. If that is not the case, then please share full information.

Comment: Well, XSLT is a publicly accessible W3C standard, you can find the definition of `xsl:import` at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#import which says "The xsl:import element is only allowed as a top-level element. The xsl:import element children must precede all other element children of an xsl:stylesheet element," so what you have tried doesn't make any sense and should give an error. It is also not clear what `Cross.xml` is, is that another XSLT stylesheet module?

Comment: @Martin Honnen, the first one is the Cross.xml and the second one is hannimpeha.xsl which is made by me

Comment: Try a tutorial on XSLT, the `xsl:import` in XSLT is not used to reference any XML input data, it is used to import further XSLT modules if necessary.